# upload data from .csv with multiple worksheets

Tags: csv, spreadsheet

can anyone please tell me how to upload the data from a .csv file on to a webpage which has 4 worksheets with different number of coloums and rows data.

Comment: This is definitely programming related as far as I can tell, but perhaps I'm interpreting the question wrong. We'll only know if the OP can clarify his request a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a PHP script or a script in another programming language which will read through the .csv, and then display the data using `<table>s` on the web page.